# Is there search options in PowerShell it could look entire sub registry

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find 2  registry values I don't have exact path it could be anywhere in sub registry. Is there search options in PowerShell it could  look entire sub registry.  Find it and replace it with new value? I tried to use (*) it didn't find anything. Example is below

Current:

```
Hklm:\system\test value 10.0.0.5
Hklm:\systen\subvalues\test2 value 10.0.0.6
```

Change to:

```
Hklm:\test value 10.0.0.7
Hklm:\subvalues\test2 value 10.0.0.9
```

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What's the logic here?

Comment: So what you really are asking is to how to change some printer's IP address?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet, but Get-ItemProperty is primarily used to get registry subkey info.

For instance, while not elegant, this will do what you are looking for.

```
Get-Item -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -path  
"Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\Test" |
foreach {
    Get-ItemProperty -Path "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::$_" | 
   foreach {
        $CurrentUserShellFoldersPath = $_.PSPath
    $_.PSObject.Properties |
    foreach {
        if ($_.Value -like "10.0.0.5") {
            write-host "Old Value:`t"$_.Value
            $newValue = $_.Value
            $newValue = $newValue -replace '10.0.0.5', "10.0.0.6"
            Set-ItemProperty -Path $CurrentUserShellFoldersPath -Name $_.Name -Value 
            $newValue
           }
        }
    }
}
```